# Markers with on hover innerHTML

Tags: csv, d3.js, leaflet, latitude-longitude, marker

I am creating a Map datavisualisation with Leaflet js. And I am running into a (probably easy solved) problem. But I can't figure it out.

I have a div with an ID which is "zipcode"

```
<div id="zipcode></div>
```

And I am trying to change the text content of this div on a hover of a specific marker that has been plotted on the Map. I tried something like this:

```
marker.on('mouseover', function (e) {
    this.openPopup();
    document.getElementById("zipcode").innerHTML = rows[i]['postcode'];
});
```

The variable `rows[i]['postcode']` is a value from a CSV which I load in with d3. This looks like:

```
d3.csv("data/data.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    client: d.Client,
    postcode: d.Postcode,
    plaats: d.Plaats,
    totaal: d.Totaal,
    budget: d.Budget,
    besteed: d.Besteed,
    percentage: d.Percentage,
    latitude: d.Lat,
    longitude: d.Long,
    street: d.Street
  };


  }, function(error, rows) {

     for(i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
        var latitude = rows[i]['latitude'];
        var longitude = rows[i]['longitude'];
        var percentage = rows[i]['percentage']/100;
        var street = rows[i]['street'];


        var cssIcon = L.divIcon({
           // Specify a class name we can refer to in CSS.
           className: 'css-icon',
           // Set marker width and height
           iconSize: [rows[i]['budget']/25+10, rows[i]['budget']/25+10]
        });

        var marker = L.marker([latitude,longitude], {icon: cssIcon, opacity: percentage}).addTo(map);
  }
});
```

Unfortunatly I can't find a solution for this. Please help me!

Comment: I think this is the line which causes teh issue _rows[i]['postcode'];_ i is not present in the mouse over event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the data associated with the marker like this:

```
for(i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
        var latitude = rows[i]['latitude'];
        var longitude = rows[i]['longitude'];
        var percentage = rows[i]['percentage']/100;
        var street = rows[i]['street'];


        var cssIcon = L.divIcon({
           // Specify a class name we can refer to in CSS.
           className: 'css-icon',
           // Set marker width and height
           iconSize: [rows[i]['budget']/25+10, rows[i]['budget']/25+10]
        });

        var marker = L.marker([latitude,longitude], {icon: cssIcon, opacity: percentage}).addTo(map);
        marker.myData = rows[i];//setting the data
  }
```

Then in side your event you should be able to get the row data

```
marker.on('mouseover', function (e) {
    this.openPopup();
    document.getElementById("zipcode").innerHTML = this.myData.postcode;
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly!